# How to log variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

`for i in *.txt;
do
xxd -l 3 $i >> log
done`

I also want to log file names `$i` for each result. E.g.:

`file_name
result_of_command`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. You mean you just want to do this: echo "$i" >> log ? Please be more clear in what you are looking for.

Comment: @jeremy-gurr, yes I want $i, followed by the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear what you are asking, but is this what you want?

```
for i in *.txt;
do
    echo "$i" >> log
    xxd -l 3 $i >> log
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to put `echo` in a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to use `printf`:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "$f" "$(xxd -l 3 "$f")"
done >> log
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `find` with the `-exec` option to run a command for every file matching certain criteria.

If you want all files in your current directory matching `*.txt` you can use `find`. You can use the `-exec` option to run a command for each file. `{}` replaces the name of the file and `\;` (an escaped `;` terminates the command). You can use `+` instead to tell find to replace `{}` with multiple filenames.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -exec xxd -l 3 {} \; >> log
```

Note that the above example includes hidden files, you can exclude them using a regex.

```
 find . -type f \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -name '*.txt'  -maxdepth 1 -exec xxd -l 3 {} \; >> log
```

Also, if you're going to be globbing files in the current directory and using them in commands, always use `./*`. Paths beginning with `-` are likely to be interpreted by your command as options.

Comment: I don't think a for loop suffers from either of these deficiencies. According to [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/), it's actually a cure for commands with too lang an argument list; and filenames with spaces are handled just fine by globs.

Comment: @benjaminw I think you're right. Does using a literal glob pattern in a for loop split on any character in IFS or does the loop variable always match one complete path that the glob could have expanded into?

Comment: It matches the complete path, I'd say.

Comment: Fixed. I was remembering a different gotcha with looping over lines in a file :/